# python 2.5 uninstalled, 2.7 and 3.4 installed - /2.5/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python, macos, installation, uninstallation, versions

I have uninstalled python 2.5 and installed 2.7 and 3.4 on my Mac OS X 10.9.2.
Somehow when i try to install a new module, i am getting the following error

```
Thomass-MacBook-Pro:dev thomas$ pip install lxml
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I googled and tried things for hours, played around with symlinks but somehow the system still thinks that 2.5 is the standard version.

Comment: Reinstall pip, it's still referring to the older version.

Comment: already tried to re-install pip, but not working.
`Thomass-MacBook-Pro:dev thomas$ which pip
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip
Thomass-MacBook-Pro:dev thomas$ pip install lxml
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`

Comment: `sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip`

Comment: Have you tried to install with "easy_install lxml" ? if It works, try then "sudo easy_install Distribute"

Comment: @RobertoSánchez, via easy_install it is working... same for Distribute.

Comment: @devnull is says "File exists"

Comment: Add the `-f` option, i.e. `-fs` instead of `-s`.

Comment: @devnull, awesome, works now!

Answer (score 0):

Check what Python version are using `pip` command

```
 head -1 /usr/local/bin/pip | sed s/#\!//g
```

In my OSX, the python is:

```
/usr/bin/python
```

Then, check that python version:

```
/usr/bin/python -V
```

If you get 2.5 then something was wrong with your python runtime upgrade, replace the first line in /usr/local/bin/pip by the python2.7 executable. This is not elegant, but It should work temporary until you get clear your system

Comment: i tried that solution as well, but didn´t get it  working, uninstalled pip already several times.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a bit odd, but in googling for my similar error* , I found this post and decided to try restarting my machine. That actually made everything start working, which makes me think there was a caching issue. I see this issue opened was about a week ago for you, so hopefully you're in better shape now.

* virtualenv-2.7 thought that was associated with a recently uninstalled python3.4, but virtualenv correctly was associated with 2.7